# Nikon 50mm 1.8g vs 1.8d?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-design, 50mm

What are some pros and cons of each? I use a Nikon D600 and am looking for my 50mm. I shoot a lot of video, so a smooth manual control is important to me. Besides that, I am unsure of what exactly I want. Are there any significant performance differences? Any differences in the way you would use them? Weight? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please slow down with the posting and read the [help center](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - I suspect a lot of your questions are going to be closed one way or the other right now.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've read about these two lenses, 1.8D may be all you need on a D600. The G has more distortion, but also rounder blades which give it smoother bokeh.  So it may depend on the kind of shooting you do.

The biggest upgrade with the G is that it's compatible with D3000 & 5000 series DX cameras, but that won't matter to you with your D600.

I have the G and love it, but I also have a D5100 and needed the G for compatibility.  You can use either, so it's a win-win for you.  If I had a D600 I'd go with the 1.4G myself, but that's not what you asked. :)